# Amazon Lightsail Bitnami user mysql access denied at the time of new use creation

Tags: bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have created Amazon Lightsail instance. And started a fresh wordpress site, now i connected phpmyadmin vie putty .ppk file its connected successfully with user bn_wordpress but if i want to create new database in this user it shows:

**

> Access Denied for user bn_wordpress@localhost to database NEW_CREATED_DB

**

I just want to know how can i proceed to create new password. I am new to AWS Lightsail. Please provide answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bn_wordpress user doesn't have privileges to create databases. In this case, you will need to use the "root" user and the credentials we configure during the boot process to access phpMyAdmin and create that new database you want to create.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it means a lot to me. I am seriously fade up in this process.
Please help me to know how can i get root user password, how can i get complete process to create database using root user, thanks in advance.

Comment: The root password is the same one we configure for you to access the application. You can try to follow the [Lightsail guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/find-credentials/#using-amazon-lightsail) or simply open the bitnami_credentials file to get the password: `cat ~/bitnami_credentials`.

Comment: I am still getting error, plz help me to get rid of this error, actually i downloaded .pem key from instance and i am using windows so i converted .pem key to .ppk vie puttygen and then i connect using putty by passing this .ppk file, ts logged in when i use bitnami username and http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/index.php this url works fine, but i am not able to create new database here, i can only view this. I have to upload multisite wordpress site on lightsail instance that is why i have to create new database, please let me know the correct solution, if you know better...plz

Comment: Thanks @Jota Martos for the help, i solved this issue vie login root user and application password.

Answer (score 0):

Complete setup was correct:
1. Download .pem file from lightsail instance
2. Convert it into .ppk extension vie puutygen
3. Connect 127.0.0.1 vie putty software and ppk key.
4. Access phpmyadmin vie http://127.0.0.1:8888/phpmyadmin/index.php
5. Login successfully with root credentials.

Thanks.